# regex won't capture first word in a text document. is it because nothing precedes it?

Tags: java, regex

**I'm using a 3rd party app which uses java's flavor of regex to capture matches. I sadly cannot implement any java code that would add something to the beginning of the html document before running the regex search because it is not allowed in the app. It has so many features that are worth using rather than the traditional way, otherwise I would do it that way.**

This HTML document literally only has `<br>` tags in it but always has a space after each sentence regardless of the `<br>` tags used to designate a new paragraph.

I started it with this because of the html tags and before I noticed it wasn't capturing the first word:

```
[\s](.*?)[.!?]\s
```

I tried it with a word boundary after that didn't work, but then it started to grab 'br>' with each match:

```
[\b](.*?)[.!?]\s
```

This way it would haved capture everything from a white space or word boundary to the punctuation completing the sentence followed by white space.

**This works for every other sentence in the whole document except it drops off the first word of the document every single time on all the different documents.** Probably because nothing exists before The first word at all?

Here is some sample text from the **very beginning**:

```
The troll who who lived under the bridge was quite sad. He couldn't help from 
trolling without making others mad. He had no friends because of this, but he
could never stop. It made his constantly feel alone. No other soul would comfort
him. <br>
```

This always returns the sentences like so:

```
troll who who lived under the bridge was quite sad
He couldn't help from trolling without making others mad
He had no friends because of this, but he could never stop
etc...
```

As you can see it's missing the first one on the first sentence.

**It always drops off the first word since nothing exists before it (at least this is what I'm assuming).**

**How do I get this to work?**

Comment: `[\\b\\s]` should be the same as `\\b`. Can you try that instead?

Comment: That's thing I tried and it didn't work. There is also poorly coded html bits in the document "`<br>`" that start a capture at `br> One day the troll decided to ask...` which is why I wrote it with a `\s` at first but then added the `\b` later to try to capture the first word.

Comment: Looks like you didn't provide a complete sample for us to look at. Sounds like you are trying to extract these from documents then that have HTML tags that you want to also ignore. This was not mentioned in your question - please update your question.

Comment: `\b` within a character class is not a word boundary, but a backslash. So either use simply `\b`, but since you said that doesn't suffice, try `(\b|\s)`

Comment: @KevinBrock will do. It will be a very simple add.

Comment: Never parse HTML with a regular expression, use a real HTML parser, has SO not learned this lesson yet?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson. It has. It is usually the first thing I'm posting. But it looks like the OP is very restricted in his choice of tools. Plus, he said the only HTML tags that appear in the input are `<br>`. Under this assumption the problem is solvable with regular expressions.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson m.buettner is right. **VERY, VERY** restricted. I already know about the chaos and torture one endures when trying to parse html with regex, but that is technically not what I'm doing.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson we also don't know why the html was written this way. I think they were loading html files into a php file (which is no longer live) for css format reasons. I don't think any normal person would have a reason to search for these files, but we need the text from them. Its on one of partners site. We have access to the urls, but not the files themselves which is why we are using the app to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution that I tested in PHP (but it shouldn't be using regex features that are not available in Java).

```
/\b([^<>]*?)[.!?]\s/
```

Since you are saying that the only HTML tags that are included in your string are `<br>` you can simply say that sentences can only contain characters that are neither `<` nor `>`. For that, I simply replaced `.*?` by `[^<>]*?` (which is a negated character class).

Comment: The lookbehind assertion gave it problems but worked like this without using a lookbehind assertion at all. `([^<>]*?)[.!?]\s` I've noticed it automatically doesn't match within a match

Comment: What do you mean? Why would it match within a match? You might also try just `\b` instead of the lookbehind (it's a bit overkill to be honest).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't sure if it would match like `The troll who who lived under...` and `troll who who lived under...` and `who who lived under...`. Just a misunderstanding on my part. HA just disregard it

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a regex that **requires** a word-boundary before the each word (`[\b\s] ...`). Because of that, for any text that doesn't start with a word-boundary, the regex will not match the first word.
Try using `"\\s+|\\w+|\\p{Punct}+"` instead, it will give you separate matches for groups of whitespace (1), groups of letters and/or numbers(2) and groups of punctuation characters(3).

A test with the following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+|\\w+|\\p{Punct}+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Hello world! How are you?");

int i=0;
while(m.find()){
  System.out.printf("[%02d] - %s",i,m.group());
  i++;
}
```

returns:

```
[00] - Hello
[01] -  
[02] - world
[03] - !
[04] -  
[05] - How
[06] -  
[07] - are
[08] -  
[09] - you
[10] - ?
```

---

**Update:**

Extracting sentences from text is difficult because words (lower-level) use some of the same boundaries.

Depending on your specific sentences, you might be able to make a successful regex-based solution, but you are likely not going to be able to handle all possible sentence formats without using Java, C or other "console" language.

For example, your current code will not handle sentences ending with `:`, `;` or `%`; But  the solution can be achieved with regex.

But there are cases that regex alone won't be able to handle; In particular, composed sentences like `"\"I'll quit being a troll!\" - The troll said."`.

Comment: Well, Isn't it a regex that I provide? `Pattern` and `Matcher` are not modifying the pattern-string in any way; They are just present as a simple way to test the pattern. --- BTW, I did read all of it, and I suggest you assume I did before you assume I didn't.

Comment: Your answer had code in it (which I can't use) which is why I said what I said. I can't test it that way. I guess somewhere along the editing there it removed me saying I wanted to only capture sentences.

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum Answer updated to address the sentences issue.

Comment: Oh shucks I wish I had seen this yesterday!! adding the most common characters used in a story fixed a good number of the weirdness some of the catches were doing